# Debug function not appearing in the menu bar in VS Code. I am using it for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, data-science

I am new at learning Python and i am trying to trying to set up the environment on VS code. However, the Debug icon and function is not on the menu bar. Please how do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

right click on the menu bar. you can select which menus are active. it's also called run i believe.